# Log Every document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to `console.log()` every time a `document.write()` occurs?

Something like this (which doesn't seem to work):

```
$(document).on('write', function() {
  console.log('write occurred');
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using document.write?

Comment: I'm not. I want to know when anything gets added to the dom. What do you suggest logging instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the best way to do it, but you could redefine `document.write`.

```
document.__write = document.write; // copy the original definition

// redefine
document.write = function(contents) {      
  console.log(contents); // log      
  document.__write(contents); // call the original
}
```

PS - To monitor for changes to the DOM, you should be using something more robust like [Mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents)

Comment: Thanks xbonez - Mutation events looks like exactly what I'm after.